# What's the difference between the White Tanooki Mario and the regular one?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I am having trouble with level 3-5 (read: I die all the time), and apparently the game decided to help me out, by placing an item box at the beginning of the level with a white and yellow striped Tanooki Leaf in it.

While I appreciate the help, and think I look much better in the white Tanooki suit than I ever did in the brown one, I can't help but wonder...

Are there more than aesthetic differences between the white and regular Tanooki suits? I can't tell (I am still dying a lot, in pretty much the same places, because it doesn't help me with timing my jumps... XD).

Comment: Worth noting is that by getting the option to use white Tanooki suit, i.e dying more than 5 times in a single level, you disqualify yourself from getting shiny/glittery stars on your profile. Just FYI...

Comment: @JohnoBoy if I go back later and redo the level with less dying, can I get those stars?

Comment: @AshleyNunn The stars that appear on your profile become shiny **only** if you beat the game without a Super/White Tanooki Suit/Leaf appearing (Not dying 5 times in one attempt of a level). Once you see it, there is no way to get shiny stars unless you create a new game.

Comment: No, once you've seen the white leaf block appear, even if you haven't used it, and saved your game, you're disqualified. I've learned this the hard way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The White Tanooki suit gives Mario the powers of the Tanooki suit plus invincibility for the whole level.

Comment: Awesome! I probably would've noticed that, had I not fallen down the first jump and died, over and over and over. :(